# Troubleshooting Virtualbox shared folders as it relates to Linux headers/kernel

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

Trouableshoot

**Host**: Windows 7

**Guest**: Debian Linux

**Tried**: Installing Guest Additions, installing headers, re-installing headers, installing DKMS, creating vboxsf group/users

**Problem**: Guest Additions appears to have problems with headers or the kernel configuration or something...

Guest Additions has been inserted installed several times, but it keeps failing on the Shared Folders section of the installation.

The problem seems to be with the linux headers, though I've installed, uninstalled, and re-installed what seem to be the correct headers based on `uname -a`.

```
root@debian:/media# uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@debian:/media# apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all' for regex 'linux-headers-3.16.0.4'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64' for regex 'linux-headers-3.16.0.4'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common' for regex 'linux-headers-3.16.0.4'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all-amd64' for regex 'linux-headers-3.16.0.4'
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common set to manually installed.
```

after the successful installation of the headers, I try installing Guest Additions (Shared Folders support):

```
root@debian:/media# sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.3.12 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 4.3.12 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...done.
Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Installing the Window System drivers
Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing
X Window System drivers.
 ...done.
Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
```

So, I had a look at the log file mentioned in the error message above:

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.12/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxguest-4.3.12

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.16.0-4-amd64 -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.12/build............(bad$
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-4-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.12/build/make.log for more information.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
grep: /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 \
KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common \
KBUILD_EXTMOD="/tmp/vbox.0" -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/Makefile \
modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
   gcc-4.8 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include -I/usr/src/$
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then ./scripts/recordmcount  "/tm$
   gcc-4.8 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include -I/usr/src/linux-$
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest.c: In function ‘VBoxGuestCommonGetHandledEventsLocked’:
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest.c:82:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     uint32_t u32AllowedGuestCaps = pSession->u32AquiredGuestCaps | (VMMDEV_EVENT_VALID_EVENT_MASK & ~pDevExt->u32AcquireMode$
```

I searched on one of the early errors in the log file and found this. Not sure if it's related:

https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3807

Comment: start here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp46457703730512 make sure you install DKMS before performing the install, the headers, and I usually install `build-essential` as well to make sure the gcc requirement is met. I've not had much problem installing the guest additions in Wheezy or Jessie.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks. DKMS is definitely installed. I will check on gcc and build-essential.

Comment: @FrankThomas Didn't do the trick :/